# Which classifier is best according to given table

Tags: machine-learning

```
Classifier     Precision   Recall   Accuracy    
Random Forest  0.56201    0.39200    0.85946    
Adaboost       0.33204    0.29950    0.79954
```

Since it is classification I know that its not the correct way to tell the best accuracy will result best classifier .Can I know best classifier among Random Forest and adaboost

Comment: how do you define the `best`? what's your end goal that you want to achieve? do you want less false positives, less false negatives or overall less mis-classification rate?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "none". The long answer is "the question is invalid thus you cannot provide any definite answer". The missing bit here is **what it means for you that something is the best**, you **have to** specify exactly what is the problem you are facing. Once you do  that, you can design an evaluation metric that measures it, and select the classifier maximizing it.

For example if the question is "I assume that my training data comes from the same source as the data I will be interested in the future. Furthermore, it has been created in an IID manner. I want to maximize the probability of the correct classifications in the future" then the answer is - just look at the accuracy.

In general it is not true that you cannot choose a model based on a single characteristic, you simply need to choose a characteristic that measures what you are after, that's all.